# Opencv linker in Linux c++

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

Hy guys I am trying to link a simple application write in c++ and in which I am using opencv library, in this application I am using IP cameras.

I am trying to make an executable for this application with this command:

```
g++ IPCamera.cpp -o camera -L/usr/include/opencv2 -lopencv_core -pthread -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml
```

and the output is like it unrecognized the libraries, this is the output:

```
IPCamera.cpp:12:30: error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
IPCamera.cpp:13:39: error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
IPCamera.cpp:14:39: error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp: No such file or directory
IPCamera.cpp:18:22: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
IPCamera.cpp:23: error: 'cv' is not a namespace-name
IPCamera.cpp:23: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
IPCamera.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
IPCamera.cpp:53: error: 'cv' has not been declared
IPCamera.cpp:53: error: expected ';' before 'cap'
IPCamera.cpp:59: error: 'Display' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:59: error: 'disp' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:59: error: 'XOpenDisplay' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:60: error: 'Screen' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:60: error: 'scrn' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:60: error: 'DefaultScreenOfDisplay' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:70: error: 'cv' has not been declared
IPCamera.cpp:70: error: expected ';' before 'frame'
IPCamera.cpp:73: error: 'cv' has not been declared
IPCamera.cpp:73: error: 'CV_WINDOW_NORMAL' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:75: error: 'cvMoveWindow' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:80: error: 'CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:80: error: 'CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:80: error: 'cvSetWindowProperty' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:96: error: 'cap' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:99: error: 'frame' was not declared in this scope
IPCamera.cpp:106: error: 'cv' has not been declared
IPCamera.cpp:109: error: 'cv' has not been declared
```

So I think that I am not liking the libraries properly, someone could help me?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this

```
g++ main.cpp -o a.out `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags`
```

So for you it should be:

```
g++ IPCamera.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags`
```

The command `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags` will return all the flags necessary for your program to work.

Be aware that OpenCV is registered with pkg-config.
If you installed OpenCV from Ubuntu repository it should work without any problem

Comment: Hi JMB I tried you suggestion and it works propertly, my problem is that I want to run my application in an ARM so I need to make the croos compile so I try this: arm-linux-g++ IPCamera.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags` but it does work, is appear the same error like the begining, how should I compile with croos compile?

Comment: Other thing is when I compile in your way I get an executable, if I try to execute it I get an error like 'expected end line (expected")")' but in eclipse there is nothing. I hope you can help me thank you

Comment: @user3536692 Did you compile OpenCV yourself or just downloaded it ? If want to use OpenCV for ARM, the executable and the OpenCV Lib have to be compiled in arm. You can compile OpenCV arm from your computer. There is a tutorial here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html

Comment: Actually I am not sure, because the enviroment was configurate by other guy, How can I know that?I am going to see your tutorial. Thank you again

Comment: I compiled already other aplication for the ARM with binaries like this:     arm-linux-g++ Prototipo.o RecvRawEth.o -o execute2 -pthread. and it works perfect, but I do know why it does not work with opencv

Comment: I just tried this: cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/include/opencv2/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake /usr/include/opencv2

Comment: And I get this: CMake Error: The source directory "/usr/include/opencv2" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI. Thank you again and sorry for my unknowledge

Comment: @user3536692 No,you shouldn't use the directory `/usr/include/opencv2/`. In the tutorial it's written `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path to the OpenCV source directory>/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake <path to the OpenCV source directory>` the path to the OpenCV source directory is not the one installed on your system, but the one from the source code you just downloaded through Git or Sourceforge.

Comment: Hi JMBise finally I got finish the installation but now How can I compile and link the opencv librariess??

Comment: @user3536692 with the command line in the answer to the question. The command `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags` will output all the necessary flags, you don't need to worry where the opencv library is located pkg-config will do it for you.

Comment: Hi JMBise, When I do the command you told me is working perfect but how I told you I need the cross compilation for ARM, when I compile with this:     g++ IPCamera.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags`     I get the .exe but it does not work fir my ARM because It has not been compiled with cross compile. thank you

Comment: @user3536692 yes sorry, just use arm-linux-g++ instead of g++. Also make sure that `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags` return the flasgs for arm, if not just replace the path returned by that command with the newly compiled opencv libs for arm.

Comment: Hi JMBise when I write this: arm-linux-g++ IPCamera.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags` nothing happend, just return erro due is missing the libraries, it does not retunrn any flags

Answer (score 0):

if you ran 'make install', it's probably :

```
-I/usr/local/include
-L/usr/local/lib
```

(/usr/local is the default install path)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but I do not have anything in usr/local/lib